# SQL Oracle, dynamic PL/SQL pivot in function

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, pivot, transpose

I have the script below that pivots (transposes) rows to columns (column names are stored in variable "r", values in "v", while "A" and "B" are the identifiers that will remain on the rows after pivoting):

```
drop table T_out;
declare
      q2     clob;
      cols   clob;
    begin    

      select listagg(''''||r||''' as '||r||' ', ',') within group (order by r)
      into cols from (select distinct r from T);

     q2 :=
     'create table T_out as
      select * from
      (select A, B, r, v from T)
      pivot
      ( sum(v) for r in ('||cols||') )';

      execute immediate q2;
end;
/
```

I tried to turn it in a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE transpose(T IN char, riga IN char, classe IN char, valore IN char) 
IS
      q1   clob;
      q2   clob;
      cols clob;
BEGIN
      q1 :=
      'select 
      listagg(''''''''||'||riga||'||'''''' as ''||'||riga||'||'' '', '','') 
      within group (order by '||riga||')
      into cols 
      from (select distinct '||riga||' from '||T||')';

     dbms_output.put_line(q1);
     execute immediate(q1);

      q2 :=
     'create table '||T||'_out as
      select * from
      (select '||classe||', '||riga||', '||valore||' from '||T||')
      pivot
      ( sum(v) for  '||riga||' in ('||cols||') )';

    dbms_output.put_line(q2);    
    execute immediate(q2);         

end;
```

However, running:

```
execute transpose('T','r', 'A, B', 'v');
```

I get the error:

```
Error starting at line : 35 in command -
BEGIN transpose('T', 'r', 'A, B', 'v'); END;
Error report -
ORA-00905: missing keyword
ORA-06512: at "USER12345.TRANSPOSE", line 18
ORA-06512: at line 1
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

The issue is in executing the "q1" query, but I cannot figure out what the missing keyword is...the DBMS output for "q1" seems to be identical to the part running in the script version:

```
select listagg(''''||r||''' as '||r||' ', ',') 
      within group (order by r)
      into cols 
      from (select distinct r from T)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you changed the first part to be dynamic -- clearly this is the issue since that is the change you made from the working code.

Comment: The first part needs to be dynamic since I have to be able to choose different grouping variables names, table names, etc. Could I do this in a non dynamic way,  giving the inputs not as char?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easier if you call listagg with the 2nd parameter `''','''` and then just prepend and append a single `'`

Also, to debug just print out the generated line -- you will probably see your problem right away (an extra `'` I'm guessing).

Comment: Hi, the debug actually seems to have the correct number of " ' "